# full background one page first div intro

Tags: ios, css, background, responsive-design, parallax

I have a bug, I have a onepage website with a intro div with content and a background picture.
Everything works fine, only not on the iphone.

The picture on iphone is fully zoomed in, but on android it works fine.
This is the css code for the intro div:

```
#intro{
background: url('../images/index_pic.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
overflow: hidden;
width:100%;
height:100%;
z-index: 1;
}
```

I take it from this site: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

How can I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by fully zoomed in? Any chance of a screenshot?

Comment: http://wouterschoofs.be/iphone.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This css code doesn't work for iPhone. 
When you want full backgrounds you must use this Jquery library -> http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/